# Kraft's inequality and Shannon's noiseless coding theorem for an encoding

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, entropy, huffman-coding

A discrete memoryless source **W** has words $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5,w_6$ that occur with probablilities $0.05,0.05,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3$ respectivley.

Does there exist a compact instantaneous binary encoding for this source with word lengths $2, 2, 4, 4, 5$ and $5$?

Shannon's Noiseless coding theroem that says a compact encoding has expected wordlength $n$ where $n\leq \frac{H(W)}{\log_2(D)}$.
I get $H(W)=2.328$ and $n=1.901$, but in this case the expected word length is $3.67$ so it cannont be a compact encoding.

I feel like I have gone wrong here, could somebody tell me how? Because I have gone on to the next question where I perform Huffman coding to achieve a compact instantaneous encoding however the word length for this encoding is *still* higher than $1.901$ so fee like I must have my value for $n$ wrong but can't see how?

Comment: [Also posted on Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162257/krafts-inequality-and-shannons-noiseless-coding-theorem-for-an-encoding). [Please don't do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what a "compact instantaneous binary encoding" is, but I'm guessing it's a prefix code that saturates Kraft's inequality. If so, your numbers don't correspond to a *compact* prefix code, since $1/4+1/4+1/16+1/16+1/32+1/32 < 1$.

Shannon's noiseless coding theorem states that when optimally encoding *large blocks*, in the limit the average encoding size per data item is the entropy. You can prove the upper bound part of the theorem using Huffman coding *applied to large blocks*. Huffman coding produces a code whose average bit length is at most $H(X)+1$, where $X$ is the source. If you use Huffman coding on blocks of size $n$, the average bit length per data item becomes $H(X)+1/n$ (why?), and by letting $n\to\infty$, you can get as close to the entropy as you want.